# Can swamp eels be used for unagi like American or Japanese eels?

Tags: substitutions, ingredient-selection, seafood, japanese-cuisine

So, at my local fishmarket, there is both live and frozen yellow swamp eel. I was not able to find very much on texture, flavor, or otherwise, so I was wondering if any of you have had much experience cooking with it, and is it suitable to make unagi with? Here are some photos of it if you don't know what I am talking about (live and frozen in that order):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Despite the name, [swamp eels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swamp_eel) are not true eels, and hence they are unrelated to the [Japanese eel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_eel) (*unagi*).  As far as I can tell they are also unknown in Japan and not used for food there.

That said, the Japanese *[kabayaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabayaki)* style of cooking most commonly associated with eels is also applied to any number of long, skinny, fishy creatures.  So I'd say give it a shot, and tell us how it went!